# How to include plugins when exporting my chart?

Tags: highcharts

How do I include plugins for use with the highcharts-export-server? I am trying to use the highcharts-regression plugin.

I tried to use the `-resources` option to specify the plugin's JS file (both as a local file and as a full URL) file but no regression lines are added to my charts, unlike my browser based version which has the regression lines added.

My command is:

```
highcharts-export-server
    -resources: {"files":"https://github.com/streamlinesocial/highcharts-regression/blob/master/highcharts-regression.js"}
    -instr '{"chart":{"type":"line"},"title":{"text":"Total Downtime"},"xAxis":{"type":"datetime","dateTimeLabelFormats":{ day: "%b %Y"}},"yAxis":{"allowDecimals":false,"min":0,"tickInterval":1,"title":{"text":"Percentage"}},"series":[{"name":"BOILER 04/WATERWALL","color":"#2f7ed8","regression":true,"regressionSettings":{"name":"BOILER 04/WATERWALL trend","type":"linear","dashStyle":"dash","color":"#2f7ed8"},"data":[{"x":1451599200000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1454277600000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1456783200000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1459461600000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1462053600000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1464732000000,"y":4.97,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1467324000000,"y":4.89,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1470002400000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1472680800000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1475272800000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1477951200000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1480543200000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1483221600000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1485900000000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1488319200000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1490997600000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1493589600000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1496268000000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1498860000000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"}]}]}'
    -outfile sample.png
```

The chart is generated fine but without the regression plugin features added. The same sort of code works fine when generating the chart in the browser, not using the export-server. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with a few minor "type-o" fixes. Given the above command you've provided, I've changed `-resources: {...}` to `--resources '{...}'`, as well as `-instr` to `--instr` and `-outfile` to `--outfile`, as per the documentation. Although, I think only the colon as well as the quoting are the relevant changes:

```
highcharts-export-server 
    --resources '{"files":"highcharts-regression.js"}'
    --instr '{"chart":{"type":"line"},"title":{"text":"Total Downtime"},"xAxis":{"type":"datetime","dateTimeLabelFormats":{ day: "%b %Y"}},"yAxis":{"allowDecimals":false,"min":0,"tickInterval":1,"title":{"text":"Percentage"}},"series":[{"name":"BOILER 04/WATERWALL","color":"#2f7ed8","regression":true,"regressionSettings":{"name":"BOILER 04/WATERWALL trend","type":"linear","dashStyle":"dash","color":"#2f7ed8"},"data":[{"x":1451599200000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1454277600000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1456783200000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1459461600000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1462053600000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1464732000000,"y":4.97,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1467324000000,"y":4.89,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1470002400000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1472680800000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1475272800000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1477951200000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1480543200000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1483221600000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1485900000000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1488319200000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1490997600000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1493589600000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1496268000000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"},{"x":1498860000000,"y":0,"viewType":"M"}]}]}'
    --outfile sample.png
```

This successfully gives me the following result with Highcharts export server 2.0.24:

[image: Example result]

Also, if attempting to use an URL you should probably [point to the raw file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/streamlinesocial/highcharts-regression/master/highcharts-regression.js), but I didn't have any success doing so, so I used a local version of the `highcharts-regression.js` file.

Comment: I ran your command and sadly I still don't have a regression line on my chart. I am also using Highcharts Export Server v2.0.24

Comment: Where did you put the local highcharts-regression.js file? In the same folder where you run the command from or a different folder? Thanks

Comment: However your talk of versions made me think about my node version. I installed node.js, npm and the export-server on another laptop and now it works fine on that laptop with node v8.10.0, non-working node is v6.11.4, Thanks.

Comment: @user2519446 HES v2.0.24. Node v10.15.3. Put `highcharts-regression.js` in same folder as the command was run.

Comment: Thanks - that works. I am sad to report it might have just been another typo: file vs files in my resources.